# sql where for single column multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I need column satisfying multiple conditions. In the query below, where I have `A.Col3 IN ('1', '2', '3')`, that will match records where I have *any* of those values in `Col3`. I want results where I can match *all* of those values: where I can find Table A records for the join that match '1', '2', *and* '3'.

```
SELECT A.Col1, B.LoginID, A.Col3
FROM 
  TableA A,
  TableB B
    WHERE A.Col4 = '2015'
      AND A.Col5 = '12' 
      AND A.Col3  IN
        ('1','2','3')
      AND A.Col6 IN 
        ( SELECT col7
            FROM TableB 
            WHERE Col8 = ' ') 
      AND A.Col6 = B.col9
      AND B.LoginID IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Col6
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
      ;
```

i am trying to see of A.col3 has 3 types of values - 1 2 and 3 in the table [for A.Col1]

Comment: If you need a person's `loginid`, why don't you select it in the query?  In other words, your question doesn't make sense.  The query and the text don't match.  Once again, sample data and desired results make questions much clearer.

Comment: hI gordon , B.Col2 IS THE LOGIN iD .. i Just did not post publicly in query Regrets


Like - col1 has 3 types of col3
Col1 A
Col3 1 2 3
Col1 may have only 1 or 2 or 3 .. But I need only Col1 who has all three Col3 values of 1 2 and 3

Comment: I would suggest that you fix the question so it makes sense (that is what the "edit" button is for).  Otherwise, you might start getting votes to close.

Comment: Gordon lemme know if this edit is good

Comment: What is the problem? Does this code work? It looks fine for me, excluding cryptic names.

Comment: what's wrong with `A.Col3 IN ('1', '2', '3')`? That should do what your question text is asking for.

Comment: Ah, I see the comment, now: `But I need only Col1 who has all three Col3 values of 1 2 and 3 `. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: We still need more information to finish the query, though. The sample code is too obfuscated to understand how the GROUP BY fits with the columns in the SELECT list (what you have so far is not even legal sql by strict standards), and with no column names or sample data or actual output vs expected output we can't know how to fix the problem. Also adding a tag for which db engine you're using would be helpful.

Comment: bhai kehna kia chahte ho :D never mind some of people will definitely understand it :D

Comment: please make a fiddle with sample data and your query, and add what result  you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing some information, so I can only explain how to solve this in general terms. Let's say you have three tables: `Orders`, `OrderLines`, and `Products`. The `Orders` table has fields for `ID` (autoincrement/primary key), as well as data that won't be important here. The `OrderLines` table has columns for `OrderID`, `ProductID`, and also fields `Price`, and `Qty` that also won't be used here.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find `Orders` that have lines for Products 1, 2 and 3. You're using different entities, but the basic table structure should map to what you're trying to do, and so the techniques for solving the problem will be the same. You can do that like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderLines l1 on l1.OrderID = o.ID AND l1.ProductID = '1'
INNER JOIN OrderLines l2 on l2.OrderID = o.ID AND l2.ProductID = '2'
INNER JOIN OrderLines l3 on l3.OrderID = o.ID AND l3.ProductID = '3'
```

You can also do an **exclusion join** for records the *don't* have one of the items in your list:

```
SELECT o.ID
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN OrderLines l on l.OrderID = o.ID AND l.ProductID IN ('1','2','3')
GROUP BY o.ID --list all columns needed in the select list here
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

This option is easier to write (and may perform better) if the ProductID list could long or is dynamic, but it assumes that you won't have more than one OrderLine for a given Product in an Order.